# Error with Python Code 2.7.3

Tags: python

I'm getting this error with the code the error specified:

```
print str(i+1)+". Horse number "+str(winners[i])+" - "+str(odds(winners[i]))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I believe it may be caused by the printing of one of the objects. Thank you!

Comment: No need to rely on beliefs. Add `print locals()` before the offending line and see what it says.

Answer (score 2):

It'll be one of two problems; we have to guess here since you have not posted any code.

1. You have a local variable `str` which is a list. Rename that variable in your code, it is masking the built-in `str` function.
2. You have a local variable `odds` which is a list, and you are trying to use it as a function. Perhaps you have a function named `odds` *as well*. In than case, rename the variable.

Comment: It's probably not `str`. Although the diagnosis is correct.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I had missed the `odds()` call, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably already figured it out yourself. `str` or `odds`, probably the latter, is a list and you are wrongly trying to index it using `()`, instead of `[]`. Try the following instead:

```
print str(i+1)+". Horse number "+str(winners[i])+" - "+str(odds[winners[i]])
```

or, even better, in Python version >= 2.6:

```
print '{}. Horse number {} - {}'.format(i+1,winners[i],odds[winners[i]])
```

See the [Python Doc](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings) for more info.